# In EF5 is caching of compiled queries available for short lived context?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

We plan to use EF5 in a WCF service which will have a short lived context.
Is the cache for the compiled queries emptied when I dispose the object context?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the caching, when enabled, will be shared across all instances of a given context type within the App Domain. It wouldn't make sense to cache a compiled query directly against the given instance, since the query itself never changes for any given query expression tree. It's not the same as caching the actual data that comes back from these queries.

Comment: Yes this is the case. Microsoft are confirming this behavior here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx at section 3.2 Query Plan Caching